# How to prevent Link from messing up my radio buttons behavior?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a menu, that shows the current page in bold.
For that I am using radio buttons so that each item on the menu is a label for that radio button, and in my css I make an active item bold.

My problem is, that because the label is wrapped in a `Link` element, when an item is clicked nothing really changes. It navigates properly but the radio button sate doesn't change. Maybe everything just re renders ignoring my action?
It works just fine without the link element. Why is that? And what can I do to make it work?

This is the code for my menu component:

```
import "./styles.scss";
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Menu = () => {

  const turnToLowerCaseWithHyphen = string => {
    return (string[0].toLowerCase() + string.slice(1)).replace(" ", "-");
  };

  const renderMenuItems = array => {
    return array.map(item => {
      const smallHyphenedItem = turnToLowerCaseWithHyphen(item);
      return (
        <div className="flex-group" key={smallHyphenedItem}>
          <input
            className="menu-item__radio"
            id={smallHyphenedItem}
            type="radio"
            name="menu-items"
            onChange={() => console.log(smallHyphenedItem)}
          />
          <Link
            to={"/" + smallHyphenedItem}
            className="menu-item"
            key={smallHyphenedItem}
          >
            <label htmlFor={smallHyphenedItem} className="menu-item__label">
              {item}
            </label>
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="menu">
      {renderMenuItems(["Feed", "Search", "Contact us"])}

    </div>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

EDIT: I've tried to use a state in the menu component but that doens't help either:

```
const Menu = () => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(null);

  const turnToLowerCaseWithHyphen = string => {
    return (string[0].toLowerCase() + string.slice(1)).replace(" ", "-");
  };

  const renderMenuItems = array => {
    return array.map(item => {
      const smallHyphenedItem = turnToLowerCaseWithHyphen(item);
      return (
        <div className="flex-group" key={smallHyphenedItem}>
          <input
            className="menu-item__radio"
            id={smallHyphenedItem}
            type="radio"
            name="menu-items"
            checked={currentPage === smallHyphenedItem}
            onChange={() => setCurrentPage(smallHyphenedItem)}
          />
          <label htmlFor={smallHyphenedItem} className="menu-item__label">
            <Link
              to={"/" + smallHyphenedItem}
              className="menu-item"
              key={smallHyphenedItem}
            >
              {item}
            </Link>
          </label>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };


  return (
    <div className="menu">
      {renderMenuItems(["Feed", "Search", "Contact us"])}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

Comment: When the link fires, it's going to reload the component because it'll be navigating to a different page. You're not storing the checked state of the radio button either. You need to store it's value in `state` or if you want it to persist between pages, use redux

Answer (score 0):

This was a bit more of a headach than I've expected, but I got it working.
Like Sasha suggested, I needed to store the choice in a state using redux to have it persist between pages.

But that isn't enough. using `Link` didn't allow for the action to be executed before navigating (to my understanding).
What I had to do was instead of using `Link`, to just navigate to the page I wanted using the `history.push()` command.

This is my final working code:

```
import "./styles.scss";
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import history from "../../../history";

import { setCurrentPage } from "../../../actions";

const Menu = ({ setCurrentPage, page }) => {
  const myHistory = useHistory(history);
  console.log(page);

  const turnToLowerCaseWithHyphen = string => {
    return (string[0].toLowerCase() + string.slice(1)).replace(" ", "-");
  };

  const handleChange = (page) => {
    setCurrentPage(page);
    myHistory.push(`/${page}`)
  };

  const renderMenuItems = array => {
    return array.map(item => {
      const smallHyphenedItem = turnToLowerCaseWithHyphen(item);
      return (
        <div className="flex-group" key={smallHyphenedItem}>
          <input
            className="menu-item__radio"
            id={smallHyphenedItem}
            type="radio"
            name="menu-items"
            checked={page === smallHyphenedItem}
            onChange={() => handleChange(smallHyphenedItem)}
          />
          <label htmlFor={smallHyphenedItem} className="menu-item__label">
            {/* <Link
              to={"/" + smallHyphenedItem}
              className="menu-item"
              key={smallHyphenedItem}
            > */}
            {item}
            {/* </Link> */}
          </label>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="menu">
      {renderMenuItems(["Feed", "Search", "Contact us"])}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    page: state.page
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setCurrentPage })(Menu);
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, max-content);
  grid-gap: 3rem;
  &-item {
    &__label {
      font-family: var(--font-main);
      font-size: 1.6rem;
      transition: all 0.2s;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: var(--color-grey-medium);
      width: max-content;
      &:hover {
        color: var(--color-main);
      }
    }

    &__radio {
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
      &:checked + .menu-item__label {
        color: var(--color-main);
       }
    }
  }
}
```